Removing reCAPTCHA challenge during Firebase SMS verification in Flutter app for Android and iOS
I'm developing a Flutter app that utilizes Firebase phone number authentication for user verification. However, during the SMS verification process, users are encountering reCAPTCHA challenges, which can be cumbersome and affect user experience.
I've followed the steps provided by Firebase documentation to enable SafetyNet for Android and implemented App Check for iOS, hoping to mitigate these challenges, but users are still prompted with reCAPTCHA verification.
Here's what I've done so far:

Enabled SafetyNet for Android in the Firebase project settings and registered the necessary SHA certificate fingerprints.
Implemented App Check for iOS using App Attestation.
Ensured that my Flutter app is using the latest version of the Firebase Authentication SDK.
Tested the app thoroughly on both Android and iOS platforms after these configurations.
Despite these efforts, users continue to face reCAPTCHA challenges during the SMS verification process.
I'm seeking guidance on further steps I can take to remove the reCAPTCHA challenges entirely for both Android and iOS platforms. Are there additional configurations or settings I need to consider? Or is there a specific approach I should take to address this issue effectively?
Any insights, suggestions, or experiences shared would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!


Do you encounter reCAPTCHA challenge on release mode?
